# Can't login with email after joining Windows 10 device to Azure Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id, godaddy, office365

I'm trying to join my company's Windows 10 devices to our Azure Active Directory. I go through the setup wizard detailed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-join-device-on-network#to-join-an-already-configured-windows-10-device) and I don't run into any issues until I attempt to log in to Windows with my work email. On the login screen I get the error "We are unable to connect right now. Please check your network and try again later.". I have network connection and am able to log in to my local accounts just fine. We currently use GoDaddy Office 365 which I wouldn't doubt being the culprit to my problem, but I'm not sure... (we plan on migrating to MS Office 365 in the future)

I appreciate any tips, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that GoDaddy's implementation of Office 365 uses federated users, which does not provide the same mechanism for AAD Domain join. You can find the article on doing AAD domain join with federated users [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/hybrid-azuread-join-federated-domains) however I am not sure if GoDaddy actually provides a federated metadata endpoint.

I suspect you would have to migrate to Office 365 proper.